# UITableView orientation error after dismissing a MailComposerView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView which is in landscapeRight orientation. From this table user can mail any image after selecting. Now after sending a mail when I dismiss the mail composer view (which is also in landscapeRight orientation), it takes me back to the table, the orientation is becoming in portrait orientation. But it should be in landscape orientation. I have also set the following to force the table view in landscape, both in that table view & in mail composer view:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight animated:YES];

}
```

But still it is appearing in the portrait mode. What should I do now? Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation{
    return UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}
```

Edit:

```
#pragma mark - MFMailComposeViewController Category method

@interface MFMailComposeViewController(FixedOrientation)
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation;
@end

@implementation MFMailComposeViewController(FixedOrientation)
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    return (toInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
@end
```

Try this , this allow you present modal view controllers in preferred InterfaceOrientation.
hope it helps you.

Comment: not working bro. after dismissing the mail view, the table view gets portrait orientation.